# How to Create new Database in Neo4j Community Edition

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I have install neo4j(community edition) database in Ubuntu but there I am missing /var/lib/neo4j/conf folder.

Is that folder is restricted in community edition of neo4j

I am not able to find neo4j-server.property file so that i can create a new graph.db and relocate to neo4j like mensioned bellow

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/VQpVMCKm5Y4

Thanks All.

Comment: Have you installed Neo4j with the package manager (if so take a look at  `/etc/neo4j/`)?
What is the Neo4j version (in >3.0, there is no more neo4j-server.properties, all is in neo4j.conf) ?